# Error pushing snupkg to nuget.org, unable to configure V3 endpoint

Tags: nuget, github-actions, dotnet-cli

I have a fairly straightforward .NET Framework project ([see GitHub repo](https://github.com/EngageSoftware/EngageSoftware.Dnn.Logging)) that I want to publish to NuGet via GitHub Actions.

I'm using the `dotnet` CLI for each step (version 7.0.x, currently 7.0.202):

1. `dotnet restore --locked-mode`
2. `dotnet build EngageSoftware.Dnn.Logging.sln --no-restore --configuration ${{ matrix.configuration }} -p:VersionSuffix=${{ env.VERSION_SUFFIX }}`
3. `dotnet pack EngageSoftware.Dnn.Logging.sln --no-build --configuration ${{ matrix.configuration }} -p:VersionSuffix=${{ env.VERSION_SUFFIX }} --output dist/`
4. `dotnet nuget push dist/ --source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json --symbol-source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json --api-key ${{ secrets.NUGET_PUSH_KEY }}`

That last `dotnet nuget push` step successfully pushes the `nupkg` package file, but then fails to push the `snupkg` file, [with the following output](https://github.com/EngageSoftware/EngageSoftware.Dnn.Logging/actions/runs/4505745684/jobs/7931813227):

```
Run dotnet nuget push dist/ --source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json --symbol-source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json --api-key ***  
Pushing EngageSoftware.Dnn.Logging.0.1.0-alpha-18.nupkg to 'https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/package'...
  PUT https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/package/
  Created https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/package/ 393ms
Your package was pushed.
Pushing EngageSoftware.Dnn.Logging.0.1.0-alpha-18.snupkg to 'https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/package'...
  PUT https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/package/
  BadRequest https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/package/ 136ms
error: Response status code does not indicate success: 400 (Snupkg upload failed. Please use latest NuGet clients (v 4.9.0 or above) and a V3 endpoint to push Symbol packages. For details, refer https://docs.microsoft.com/nuget/create-packages/symbol-packages-snupkg).
```

The error indicates that it needs to use the V3 endpoint, even though I'm passing the V3 endpoint via command line arguments, and have it set as the `defaultPushSource` in `nuget.config` (it first failed b/c there wasn't a default push source, then I added `defaultPushSource` and it started working as it does presently, and added the explicit source command line arguments, which did not change anything).

The [full `nuget.config` file](https://github.com/EngageSoftware/EngageSoftware.Dnn.Logging/blob/5824904bd1f7553a610a0a72586a3ab18f817b7d/nuget.config):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<configuration>
  <solution>
    <add key="disableSourceControlIntegration" value="true" />
  </solution>
  <config>
    <add key="defaultPushSource" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" />
  </config>
  <activePackageSource>
    <add key="All" value="(Aggregate source)" />
  </activePackageSource>
  <packageSources>
    <add key="nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" />
  </packageSources>
  <packageSourceMapping>
    <packageSource key="nuget.org">
      <package pattern="*" />
    </packageSource>
  </packageSourceMapping>
</configuration>
```

The [full GitHub actions YAML file](https://github.com/EngageSoftware/EngageSoftware.Dnn.Logging/blob/5824904bd1f7553a610a0a72586a3ab18f817b7d/.github/workflows/ci.yml):

```json
{
    "name": "CI (Build and Package)",
    "on": {
        "workflow_dispatch": null,
        "push": {
            "branches": ["main"]
        },
        "pull_request": {
            "branches": ["main"]
        },
        "release": {
            "types": ["created"]
        }
    },
    "defaults": {
        "run": {
            "shell": "pwsh"
        }
    },
    "jobs": {
        "build": {
            "strategy": {
                "matrix": {
                    "configuration": ["Release"]
                }
            },
            "runs-on": "windows-latest",
            "env": {
                "NUGET_PACKAGES": "${{ github.workspace }}/.nuget/packages"
            },
            "steps": [
                {
                    "name": "Checkout",
                    "uses": "actions/checkout@v3.4.0"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Setup .NET SDK",
                    "uses": "actions/setup-dotnet@v3.0.3",
                    "with": {
                        "dotnet-version": "7.0.x"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "uses": "actions/cache@v3",
                    "with": {
                        "path": "${{ env.NUGET_PACKAGES }}",
                        "key": "${{ runner.os }}-nuget-${{ hashFiles('**/packages.lock.json') }}",
                        "restore-keys": "${{ runner.os }}-nuget-"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "name": "Restore NuGet packages",
                    "run": "dotnet restore --locked-mode"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Set version suffix to alpha-${{ github.run_number }}",
                    "if": "github.event_name != 'release' || github.event.action != 'created'",
                    "run": "'VERSION_SUFFIX=alpha-${{ github.run_number }}' >> $env:GITHUB_ENV"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Build",
                    "run": "dotnet build EngageSoftware.Dnn.Logging.sln --no-restore --configuration ${{ matrix.configuration }} -p:VersionSuffix=${{ env.VERSION_SUFFIX }}"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Package",
                    "run": "dotnet pack EngageSoftware.Dnn.Logging.sln --no-build --configuration ${{ matrix.configuration }} -p:VersionSuffix=${{ env.VERSION_SUFFIX }} --output dist/"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Upload build artifacts",
                    "uses": "actions/upload-artifact@v3.1.2",
                    "with": {
                        "path": "dist/"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "name": "Push packages to NuGet",
                    "run": "dotnet nuget push dist/ --source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json --symbol-source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json --api-key ${{ secrets.NUGET_PUSH_KEY }}"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

The [full csproj file](https://github.com/EngageSoftware/EngageSoftware.Dnn.Logging/blob/5824904bd1f7553a610a0a72586a3ab18f817b7d/EngageSoftware.Dnn.Logging/EngageSoftware.Dnn.Logging.csproj):

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net472</TargetFramework>
    <Company>Engage</Company>
    <Authors>Brian Dukes</Authors>
    <Copyright>Copyright (c) Engage Software (engagesoftware.com)</Copyright>
    <PackageProjectUrl>https://github.com/EngageSoftware/EngageSoftware.Dnn.Logging</PackageProjectUrl>
    <PackageIcon>icon.png</PackageIcon>
    <PackageReadmeFile>README.md</PackageReadmeFile>
    <PackageTags>dnn-platform logging</PackageTags>
    <PackageLicenseExpression>MIT</PackageLicenseExpression>
    <Description><![CDATA[
          Reference this project in order to enable dependency injection support for
          `ILogger<T>` in your DNN Platform site. This implementation wraps [DNN's
          `LoggerSource`](https://docs.dnncommunity.org/api/DotNetNuke.Instrumentation.LoggerSource.html),
          which ties into DNN's custom Log4Net implementation by default.
        ]]></Description>
    <VersionPrefix>0.1.0</VersionPrefix>
    <GenerateDocumentationFile>true</GenerateDocumentationFile>
    <PublishRepositoryUrl>true</PublishRepositoryUrl>
    <GeneratePackageOnBuild>false</GeneratePackageOnBuild>
    <EmbedUntrackedSources>true</EmbedUntrackedSources>
    <AllowedOutputExtensionsInPackageBuildOutputFolder>$(AllowedOutputExtensionsInPackageBuildOutputFolder);.pdb</AllowedOutputExtensionsInPackageBuildOutputFolder>
    <IncludeSymbols>true</IncludeSymbols>
    <SymbolPackageFormat>snupkg</SymbolPackageFormat>
    <EnableNETAnalyzers>true</EnableNETAnalyzers>
    <AnalysisMode>AllEnabledByDefault</AnalysisMode>
    <AnalysisLevel>latest</AnalysisLevel>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <LangVersion>latest</LangVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(GITHUB_ACTIONS)' == 'true'">
    <ContinuousIntegrationBuild>true</ContinuousIntegrationBuild>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Using Include="System"/>
    <Using Include="System.Collections.Generic"/>
    <Using Include="System.Globalization"/>
    <Using Include="System.IO"/>
    <Using Include="System.Linq"/>
    <Using Include="System.Threading"/>
    <Using Include="System.Threading.Tasks"/>
    <Using Include="DotNetNuke.DependencyInjection"/>
    <Using Include="DotNetNuke.Instrumentation"/>
    <Using Include="JetBrains.Annotations"/>
    <Using Include="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection"/>
    <Using Include="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Extensions"/>
    <Using Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging"/>
    <Using Remove="System.Net.Http"/>
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <AdditionalFiles Include="..\stylecop.json" Link="stylecop.json"/>
    <None Include="..\icon.png" Pack="true" PackagePath="\"/>
    <None Include="..\README.md" Pack="true" PackagePath="\"/>
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="DotNetNuke.DependencyInjection" Version="9.4.0" PrivateAssets="All" ExcludeAssets="runtime"/>
    <PackageReference Include="DotNetNuke.Instrumentation" Version="9.4.0" PrivateAssets="All" ExcludeAssets="runtime"/>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging" Version="7.0.0"/>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.SourceLink.GitHub" Version="1.1.1" PrivateAssets="All"/>
    <PackageReference Include="JetBrains.Annotations" Version="2022.3.1" PrivateAssets="all" ExcludeAssets="runtime"/>
    <PackageReference Include="StyleCop.Analyzers" Version="1.2.0-beta.435" PrivateAssets="all">
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Comment: what will happen if you don't configure `--symbol-source`? I publish symbols packages without it

Comment: but I do set `IncludeSymbols` in `dotnet pack ..`

Comment: It's the same behavior whether `--symbol-source` is on the command-line or not. Here's [the run with just `--source`](https://github.com/EngageSoftware/EngageSoftware.Dnn.Logging/actions/runs/4451052691/jobs/7817239502), here's [the run with neither](https://github.com/EngageSoftware/EngageSoftware.Dnn.Logging/actions/runs/4450994556/jobs/7817109673).

Comment: I set `IncludeSymbols` in the `csproj` file, and it does definitely generate the `snupkg` file, so I don't think I need to pass `IncludeSymbols` to `dotnet pack`

Comment: note: `I'm passing the V3 endpoint via command line argument` I think somehow V2 is used behind the scene. I also configure `https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json` endpoint as the source and see the following in the output for command: `Created https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/package/ ..ms` /
`Your package was pushed.` /
`Pushing PackageName.snupkg to 'https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/symbolpackage'...` / 
`PUT https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/symbolpackage/` /
`Created https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/symbolpackage/ ..ms` /
`Your package was pushed.`

Comment: `It's the same behavior whether --symbol-source` are nupkg and snupkg files placed in the same location?

Comment: Yes, both `nupkg` and `snupkg` files are built to `dist` (as the only contents of `dist`) and I'm running `dotnet nuget push dist/` to push them both.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252818/discussion-between-bdukes-and-dododo).

Comment: @bdukes: Did you try using [`--no-service-endpoint`](https://github.com/EngageSoftware/EngageSoftware.Dnn.Logging/actions/runs/4505745684/jobs/7931813227#step:10:34) flag?

Comment: `--no-service-endpoint` didn't appear to make a difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try publishing packages one by one with specifying a particular package path instead a folder